# Prevent bootstrap button groups from breaking

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, frontend, twitter-bootstrap-2

How can I prevent bootstrap button goups from breaking in to 2 lines when there is less space?

I am trying to use the below Bootstrap code:

```
   <div class="btn-group" style=" width:100px ;">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style=" width:30px;">-</button>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:30px;">   
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style=" width:30px;"> +</button>
    </div>
```

And it looks like:

[image]

Comment: add an extra style inline and change the width, eg `<div class="btn-group" style="width:300px">`

Comment: still not working. i was edited the original post.

Answer (score 19):

This is what worked for me, turn the group of buttons to a flex item (by default it does not wrap):

```
.btn-group {
  display: flex;
}
```

I saw this here, and there are more options too:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9939